# How should one interpret the term x:2a?

Tags: notation

I was asked about the right interpretation of $x:2a$. There are two ways to interpret this term $$x:2a=x:(2a)=\frac{x}{2a}$$ and $$x:2a=(x:2)a=\frac{x}{2}\cdot a$$ I am not aware of a convention in mathematics how such a term should be read. So my answer is, that expressions like the one above should be avoided (because they cannot be interpreted uniquely). Am I right with my answer?

Comment: $x:2a=\frac{x}{2}\cdot a$ is highly unikely to be the case..

Comment: In mathematics, $:$ is not used, as far as I know.

Comment: I agree with both, and I'd interpret $x : 2a = \frac{x}{2a}$ becuase of the missing multiplication sign, but this is just guessing, this notation is very ambiguous and should not be used.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: The sign ":" is used for ratios, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio (one can also replace ":" with "÷" in my question)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: But I also agree, I quasi never have seen ":" or "÷" in my lectures or textbooks. It seems to me, that those signs are only used in school...

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi: The interpretation $x:2a=\tfrac x2 a$ is used in most programming languages. For example in python one has `6 / 2 * 3 = 9`...

Answer (score 1):

The $:$ symbol is not so much a mathematical operator as it is a convenient form of notation. Thus you would never see a symbolic equation using $:$ in place of division, but you might see a ratio written verbally with it (as in your question). Furthermore, the $:$ takes all terms on the left and compares them to all terms on the right. Thus $a+b-c:efg$ is another way of expressing $\frac{a+b-c}{efg}$. Note, however, it is not "$=$" to this expression, since $:$ is not a mathematical operator in that sense (unless you define it as such).

Simply put, there is only one way to interpret the $:$ symbol, because it has either been defined as an operator and thus has a unique interpretation, or it is not a mathematical operator and hence is not "part of an expression," but rather means "the ratio between all terms on the left to all terms on the right."